# How to hide d3 heat map columns

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I am using D3 Heat Map in my application.
I am taking reference from here: http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084
Now I have a situation where I have to show/hide the columns.
How can I do this?